# Python gives ModuleNotFoundError for some python3 modules if I am not using a virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

Python gives ModuleNotFoundError for some python3 modules if I am not using a virtual environment, with the following modules:

1. uvicorn
2. flask
3. mysql.connector
   But, when I create a virtual environment, and install these modules in that environment, everything works fine. What seems to be the problem here? I have installed python on ubuntu using the sudo apt-get install  command.

Comment: You need to install those packages in the system separately. Via `apt` or via pip. While python executable in venv is a symlink to one installed in system (you may have different versions of python in the system and choose which one to use in venv) the packages are installed directly in the venv, nowhere else.

Comment: @PiotrSawicki I have installed them in system separately. My original question was - Why python is not picking those global modules, and only works when I create a virtual environment and install those packages there?

Comment: It depends on the system and a way you have installed it. My guess would be, that on debian-based distro (*buntu, Mint, ...) you have installed package like `apt install python-uvicorn` or `sudo pip install uvicorn` instead of `apt install python3-uvicorn` or `pip3 install uvicorn` or `python3.x -m pip install uvicorn`. (default is still python2) If my guess is wrong, please provide exact steps and your system details. Also using venv is generally good idea during development.